# How to add unique products in wishlist using Prisma and NextJs

Tags: database, postgresql, next.js, fetch, prisma

I have this function, it does a post request and add products  to a array. I want to add unique id's so if an id I want to add is already in the array I want to remove it from the array

```
const handleAddToWishlist = async (product) => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      toast("Trebuie să fiți autentificat pentru a adăuga produse în coș.", {
        duration: 5000,
      });
      return;
    }
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/wishlist`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: currentUser.id,
          productId: product.id,
        }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        toast.success("Produsul a fost adăugat la favorite");
        dispatch(setWishlist(data));
        console.log("data", data);
      } else {
        toast.error("Eroare. Încearcă din nou!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding to wishlist:", error);
    }
  };
```

```
export async function POST(req) {
  const data = await req.json();
  const { userId, productId } = data;

  const wishlist = await db.favorite.update({
    where: {
      id: userId,
    },
    data: {
      favorite: {
        push: productId,
      },
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(wishlist);
}
```

I thought of making an DELETE request